# POS Validate Loading

Tags: javascript, python, performance, odoo-15, point-of-sale

I was faced loading time longer in On Premise server. When validate many kit or manufacture of products in pos, loading time is very longer. I have RAM 32GB and CPU 10 core. Odoo config is set up with 
 limit_memory_soft = 10737418240,
 limit_request = 8192,
 limit_time_cpu = 600,
 limit_time_real = 1200,
  workers = 16 
I was trying to "product loading in set up of pos counter config" with product 10.How to fix it? Please help me!